# WordPress Cron Function exceed php timeout

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am trying to update StoreRocket using their REST API in a cron job. However, they have a 60-requests per minute limit. But if I put a 1-second timer after every request, the function time out at 2 minutes because the max_execution_time is set to 120. I have no way to update the max_execution_time because I do not have access to it. Is there another way around to bypass this timeout issue?

```
function cron_repeat_function () {
  $remote_api_url = "StoreRocket api url";
  $request_args = "setup request arguments";
  foreach ( $locations as $location ) { 
    $storerocket_post_request = wp_remote_post( $remote_api_url, $request_args );   
    sleep(1);                                                         
  }
}
```

Comment: My first suggestion is to use [system cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/) instead of “poor man’s cron”, which is the default. However, that doesn’t scale well. My  recommended solution is to treat this as a queue. Unfortunately, the implementation is dependent on your system and requirements. If you need a daily, you could have the main cron wake up at midnight and schedule _n_ additional one-time tasks with 10 items each. Alternatively, you could keep track of what has already run and just grab “the next” 10.

Comment: The cron job is already setup using system cron which runs at 5am.   "Alternatively, you could keep track of what has already run and just grab “the next” 10. " How do I achieve this? Do I rewite the repeat function to be a recursive one?

Comment: You could use the options table to store what is done, or the last ID that was run successfully. This kind of task can be more database intensive, too, since it isn’t user-facing, so feel free to be more verbose. You can “checkout” a single item “somehow”, and mark it is “done” or ‘’failed”. Although it might be hard to read, [here](https://github.com/vendi-advertising/vendi-abandoned-plugin-check/blob/709a2fd611cef7044d5e41536188b417cd1d5f42/vendi-abandoned-plugin-check.php#L362) is one of my plugins that takes 10 at a time and reschedules itself until completed